# how to apply Smooth vertical Scrolling in NestedScrollView in android

Tags: android

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#e7e7e8"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/communication_recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/vision_recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/hearing_recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/physical_dependency_recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/selef_care_recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This is my code i have take 6 RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView  but  when i scroll vertically smooth scrolling is not working  can any one please suggest me how to apply smooth scrolling in NestedScrollView

Answer (score 2):

Adding `recyclerviews` inside `NestedScrollView` does not make good practice. Avoid these kind of situation if possible.

 Here are some alternatives...

- Use items as `recyclerview` items - Kind of multiple type
  `recyclerview`
- Use horizontal orientation of `recyclerview` to show
  content well.

Comment: I understood this but i have requirement like this we have to take multiple recylerview

Comment: @Adevelopment You have to go for alternatives. This is the sign of poor representation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView then use `mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

If in case it does not work smoothly scrolling for RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView OR Only NestedScrollView then make sure that your compileSdkVersion match with your currently used library version.

For example. In your all build.gradle file `compileSdkVersion` 25 buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

Then your support appcompact library version

`compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1"`

if you can't find your mismatch library version then run below command in Android Studio Terminal. it should fetch currently used library version and latest library version according compileSdkVersion.

`./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile`

Answer (score -1):

NestedScrollView insinde ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```